# Fireworks image creating issue

Tags: image, adobe, fireworks

an image having blend mode as multiply,(its kind of reducing opacity) its showing its effect in adobe fireworks but its not showing the same effect,when overlapped on another image in browser.

Comment: Fireworks PNG != regular PNG...export as jpeg or something, also this is more a superuser.com question.

Answer (score 1):

Try saving the png as "flattened PNG" and choose png32 as format ;)

Comment: i did  but the given effect doesn't exist after saving.

Comment: If you want you can send me that png. I can check it, no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your Fireworks document background has no color selected as is therefore transparent.  You will also want to use PNG-32 as stecb said.  When exporting the image or using the Optimize panel (if you're exporting a slice) check that the transparency is selected and no background color is chosen.

Internet Explorer 6 won't be able to handle the transparency so try using a javascript workaround like [Supersleight](http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6)